# Method check: numerically calculate 1D integral of a 3D function

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I have a function $f(r)$ where $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$, $\forall x,y,z \geq 0$. I know the values of the function at many points, essentially I have a table of values with $r$ and the corresponding value $f(r)$, let's call these $\textbf{data}$. I am trying to calculate the integral

$\int dz'~ e^{-\frac{(z-z')}{2\sigma^2}} f(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}},z')$ over the region of interest, where $\sigma$ is a parameter whose value is known.

Here is what I did:

I uniformly picked $n$ samples of $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ and $z$ in the region of interest, where $n$ is the number of data points. For each of value of $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$, I calculated $z'=\sqrt{r^{2}- x^{2} + y^{2}}$, where $r$ is from the data. I evaluated the integrand for the list of these values. I then used $\textbf{Simpson's rule}$ to evaluate the integral over the range of $z'$.

Is this a valid method to evaluate this integral?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I am trying to calculate the integral ... over the region of interest"? Is an "of" missing after "integral"?

Comment: The region of interest is the range of $r$ from the data.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Do you mean that the range of $\mathrm dz'$ in the integral is chosen such as to match the range of $r$ from the data? But then why are you samping $z$ if you're not integrating over it? The question would make a whole lot more sense to me if there were an "of" missing after "integral" -- please check if there is.

Comment: Yes, $z'$ can range between the minimum and maximum of $r$ from the data. Don't I need the value of $z$ to compute the exponential term?

Comment: Sure you need a *value* of $z$, but if you're not integrating over it, why would you want to sample it uniformly?

Comment: Ok, how would you suggest to do this?

Comment: I can't suggest how to do it because we haven't yet succeeded in clarifying what it is you want to do. I take it that you checked that there's no "of" missing, and the formulation is as you intended it to be. Then I don't understand what $x,y,z$ are. You're not integrating over them -- so they must be fixed parameters?

Comment: I don't know what difference will the "of" make, you can add it if you like. I am trying to evaluate that integral within the range of $r$ from the data. I am only integrating over $z'$.

Comment: I see. If I understand correctly, I would suggest replacing "over" by "in", since "over" doesn't fit well and in the context of integrals sounds like "integral / integrate over", which apparently is not what you mean.

Comment: Next question: What do you mean by $f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},z')$? In the preceding paragraph you had introduced $f$ as a function of $1$, not $2$ variables.

Comment: $f$ is really a function of $x$, $y$, $z$, since it's isotropic, I can write it as $f(r)$. I am trying to take this isotropic function and "smear" it along the $z$ axis by the exponential function.  I am trying to show the $z$ dependence in the integral by that expression. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what you want to do. (And it seems you do mean "over" in the sense of "integral over"?) What I don't understand now is why you're asking the question. Why are you worried that Simpson's rule might not be a valid way to evaluate the integral?

Comment: I am new to evaluating integrals discretely, so I just wanted to check whether my understanding of sampling the variables and the way of using the Simpson's rule is correct.